# Error Installing Canon MX920 drivers - dpkg: dependency problems

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

Brand new to Ubuntu. Running a dual boot Lenovo Yoga 710. Install went pretty well. I am running 18.04.2 LTS

Went to add a Canon MX920 printer that is on my network. I got the Drivers here:

[Canon Driver Website](https://www.canon-printerdrivers.com/2016/05/canon-pixma-mx894-driver-download-mac.html)

I download cnijfilter-mx890series-3.70-1-deb and unzip it. Then I use terminal to run sudo install.sh

When it runs I get the following errors:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cnijfilter-mx890series:
 cnijfilter-mx890series depends on libpango1.0-0 (>= 1.12.3); however:
  Package libpango1.0-0 is not installed.
 cnijfilter-mx890series depends on libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.8rel); however:
  Package libpng12-0 is not installed.
 cnijfilter-mx890series depends on libtiff4; however:
  Package libtiff4 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package cnijfilter-mx890series (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 cnijfilter-mx890series
Command executed = sudo dpkg -P cnijfilter-mx890series
(Reading database ... 125749 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing cnijfilter-mx890series (3.70-1) ...
Purging configuration files for cnijfilter-mx890series (3.70-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Command executed = sudo dpkg -P cnijfilter-common
(Reading database ... 125541 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing cnijfilter-common (3.70-1) ...
Purging configuration files for cnijfilter-common (3.70-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong. The problem is that this driver package is not compatible with Ubuntu 18.04, as it requires (among others) the package `libpng12-0`, which is currently only available in 14.04 and 16.04.

You can contact Canon support to let them know of the problem, and/or install Ubuntu 16.04 (14.04 will reach end-of-life soon).

Comment: It seems like that dodges this problem and could potentially create others. I *think* I'd rather stay as current as possible making the (hopefully reasonable) assumption that eventually things are more likely to catch up to I am running 18.04.2.Whereas if I downgrade I am more likely to run into other things that stop working in the future...  Or is that not usually the case?

Comment: @MarkJoel60 Downgrading Ubuntu releases is not supported; you'd need to do a fresh install of 16.04. 16.04 is a perfectly capable system; I'm on it right now.

Answer (score 1):

Bionic actually had canon printer drivers on my installation, (Gutenprint something or other...), but they don't work right on my MX340--the colors are all wrong.

So I was struggling with installing the cnijfilter V3.90 driver for MX 340, and found the answer here (it also has many other Canon drivers, including the MG2500):

https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/10/canon-ij-printer-scangear-mp-drivers-ubuntu-18-04-18-10/

Steps are basically:

1. Remove any installed versions of cnijfilter you may have tried.

   To find old cnijfilter pkgs do

   ```
   sudo apt-cache policy cnijfilter*
   ```

   Then remove if any are installed

   ```
   sudo apt remove <your old cnijfilter pkgs>
   ```
2. Add the PPA

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thierry-f/fork-michael-gruz
   sudo apt update
   ```
3. Open Package manager, search for cnijfilter, mark for install your printer (choose your printer model here).  Mine was the MX340:

   cnijfilter-mx340series:i386
4. Open printers gui, add printer, search for network printer and apply the cnijnet address that is found.

   cnijnet:/XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX (the X's will be the mac of your printer)
5. Make sure the Canon (your model) series Ver.3.90 driver shows in Make/model window -- not the Gutenprint driver.  (mine showed the correct driver: Canon MX340 series Ver.3.90).

If for some reason the Gutenprint driver shows instead, then go back and choose the Canon (your model) series Ver.3.90 driver in the make/model window.

Comment: I am not finding cnijfilter in the packages for Ubuntu 20,04

Comment: For 20.04 I found this:  https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/05/canon-printer-scangear-mp-ubuntu-20-04/

Answer (score 1):

I solved using https://www.canon.it/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/inkjet/pixma_mx_series/mx925.html?type=drivers&driverdetailid=tcm:80-1030817&os=linux%20%2864-bit%29&language=it

installing first cnijfilter-common_3.90-1_amd64.deb
and then cnijfilter-mx920series_3.90-1_amd64.deb

if you try to install mx920 first the system respond with an error of dependencies.

Comment: I tried this in the order suggested but still got dependency error

Answer (score 0):

Well you downloaded the wrong drivers, to begin with.  You say you have an MX 920 but downloaded the 890 drivers.  https://asia.canon/support/PIXMA%20MX927/model is the right drivers for the MX 920.

Comment: When I attempt to install this driver, I get the error: "cannot satisfy dependencies"